Moving an ubuntu installation to another partition
Mostly out of curiosity:
Say that I have a secondary partition, and I copy the current instalation to it with
rsync -av --exclude={/media,/home,/proc,/dev,/sys,/tmp,/run,/mnt} / /media/new

and add it to the mbr with
update-grub

what other steps need to be taken to make it boot successfully?
(as of now, it seems update-grub did not find the new partition)

You cannot have duplicate UUIDs. If partition created in advance than that is ok, but your copy of / partition also copied files with old partitions UUIDs. You have to update all entries in / using UUID or device like /dev/sdXY.  Minimum would be entries in fstab & grub, but may be some other places also. I typically suggest new clean install so UUIDs are correct & then rsync your /home, any data, perhaps some settings in /etc, any server type installs in / and list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall. That should be your normal backup on other devices.

@oldfred this seems like the basis of a full answer

If OP wants detailed help, post the link to the Summary report. It will show the UUIDs that need update. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

@oldfred what is a "Summary report"? How can the OP generate it? And why would UUIDs be relevant here if we're setting up a new system? How can they be dupes, what would they be duplicating?

If you click on the Boot-Repair link it shows "Create Boot-info Summary Report" Just follow info in link. I typically run it regularly and include in my backups, just to document my system. User said he rsynced system to new partition. So he has two different partitions (?) but grub & fstab using same UUIDs. But need details and report shows all the detail in one place.
